# .htaccess не обрабатывает картинки

Tags: php, .htaccess

В каталоге лежит `.htaccess` и файлы jpg, php. При запросе к php получаю ошибку 403, при запросе к картинке она подгружается.

```
.htaccess

order deny,allow
deny from all
```

Пробовал добавлять `AllowOverride` в `/etc/apache2/vhosts/user/domain.com` - не помогло.

На сервере установлен ispmaneger.

Мне необходимо закрыть в этой папке все - php файлы, картинки. Куда смотреть?

Comment: какой то php фреймворк используете?

Comment: Вот все что используется:
IonCube Loader 6.0
Функции, расширения и библиотеки: iconv, mb, curl, gd, , mcrypt, soap, gmpobject, strlen, sprintf, ip2long, serialize, unserialize, crypt, parse_str, json_encode, strtr, strstr, round, parse_url, simplexml_load_string, array_search

Comment: Проверь доступ на директорию - достаточно ли прав.
Если права есть смотри логи Apache на сервере. Посмотри .htaccess в корневой директории проэкта, может там что-то переписывает путь к картинкам. Но 403 ошибка обычно возникает при недостаточных правах на файлы.